# Why some people feel afraid to ask questions?

Tags: social-psychology, psychology, behavior

Suppose, someone wants to know something about a topic. To know better me must ask questions to others about the topic.

But, there are some people who have a great curiosity for the knowledge but afraid to ask questions.

Suppose, X has a huge curiosity about maths but whenever he asks questions about it to his teacher he hesitates by thinking that this would be a very dope question and the whole class will laugh at him.

My question is why do we feel that and what can we do to prevent it?